# How to make this oddly shaped slideshows work?

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow, jquery-cycle

I want to create 2 slideshows - one beside the other ([like this](http://img814.imageshack.us/img814/471/slideshoww.jpg)). The slideshow photos will be uploaded by the user so I can't cut them up where the line is to make them transparent (they will also grow a lot in file size).

Could you please give me a few pointers on how to achieve this with jQuery (no flash)? Or direct me to a tutorial?

Thanks a lot!!

All the best,
Cris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use webkit mask, but it's only webkit.

Also canvas may be the way to go here.

But if you want broader browser support you'll have to alter the images. PHP can do this, so users uploading them is not a problem. If you're concerned about file size you could try to split image in two. One part with transparency and other regular jpg, but make sure both are loaded before you show the slide. This is only for one side of the sideshow, for the other you don't have to do anything.

Comment: I didn't expect to get an answer. Thanks a lot for taking the time to help me out. I can't go with PHP because that mean modifying the wordpress plugins and that's a bit beyond me. It looks like you know a lot about this stuff so what would you recommend I'd go with - webkit mask or canvas ? Thanks again man!

Comment: canvas has better browser support, but it's more complicated than just one line of css. To use canvas in IE < 9 you'll gave to google a script.